# How do you restart Apache?

Tags: server, apache2, services

I switched from SLES to Ubuntu and now I want to restart my local server.
In SLES I used:

```
rcapache2 restart
```

but this seems not to work in Ubuntu.

How do I restart Apache?

Comment: Next to `apache2` there is also `service apache-sp restart`

Answer (score 493, accepted):

`sudo service apache2 restart` for the way that's borrowed from Red Hat.

Comment: I think `service` is the LSB way, and should work in most distributions, now that Debian and Ubuntu *finally* got it.

Comment: `sudo restart apache2` is not working in `Ubuntu 12.04`. Not sure of other Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @saji89 you need to do `sudo service apache2 restart`, then it will work.

Comment: `sudo restart apache2` is not working in Ubuntu 14.04. `sudo service apache2 restart` is working tough.

Comment: `sudo service apache2 reload` works in some case

Comment: Could also be `service apache-sp restart`.

Answer (score 125):

Do you want to *restart* Apache, or do you want to [*gracefully reload*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/stopping.html#graceful) its configuration?

Everyone was answering the first question; you can do the second with

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Gracefully reloading is a bit faster, and there's no downtime.

There's one caveat: if your apache config files contain an error (e.g. configures a log file in a directory that doesn't exist), the server may silently exit without printing any error messages to the console.  Most other errors are caught by the `apache2ctl configtest` that `service apache2 reload` runs before doing the actual reload with `apache2ctl graceful`.

Comment: Yes! Use graceful is much better if you want to restart without kicking off your web site viewers!

Comment: I find that it's an advantage of _restart_ that if Apache isn't running then it will _start_. --> Will _reload_ also _start_ it?

Comment: I don't think so -- even worse, reload will stop a running apache if you make a syntax error in the config file.

Comment: Always run `sudo apache2ctl configtest` before doing graceful restart. Graceful restart will fail and apache will be stopped if config has a syntax error.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: thanks, I've edited the answer to drop the raw `apache2ctl graceful` and instead recommend just `service apache2 reload`, which runs the `configtest` before `graceful`.

Answer (score 29):

The recommended way under Ubuntu to start/stop services (not just
Apache) is to use the start/stop/reload commands (which really are
symbolic links to the [initctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/initctl)
program, part of [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)).

For services that use the legacy `/etc/init.d` scripts, the
corresponding script will be called with the correct parameters; for
services that use the upstart infrastructure, the appropriate event
transition will be signaled to the
[upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) daemon via
[initctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/initctl).

So, to start/stop/reload/restart apache on Ubuntu, you can use:

```
sudo start apache2
sudo stop apache2
sudo reload apache2
sudo restart apache2
```

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Of course you can swap out `restart` for `stop`, `start` and (I think) `reload`

Comment: When doing this under recent Ubuntu, you get a message about doing it the new way, although it will still carry out your the desired command.

Comment: I didn't realised Apache had moved to Upstart yet.

Comment: I don't see that message anymore.

Answer (score 19):

Ubuntu way:

1. To restart:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart|stop|start
   ```
2. To stop:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 stop
   ```
3. To start:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 start
   ```

Answer (score 12):

As Marius said graceful should be used either to restart:

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

or

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful-stop
```

to stop Apache gracefully.

These commands wait until all requests for web pages have been served before restarting/stopping the web server so that your user's don't get half a web page.

Answer (score 4):

First you check your status using this command

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

then stop the running service

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

then use this command:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

this solution has worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `systemctl` command for apache service restarting; this controls the *systemd system* and *service manager*.

**For Restarting Apache With `systemctl` Command:**

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

In case of being hung up or getting no response on restarting you can use the `systemctl stop` command to stop the service then start with the `systemctl start` command. Commands are as follows -

**For Stopping Apache With `systemctl` Command:**

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
```

**For Starting Apache With `systemctl` Command:**

```
sudo systemctl start apache2.service
```

You can also use the reload command for only reloading the apache service.

**For Reloading Apache With `systemctl` Command:**

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2.service
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use services for restarting Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

and you can use all functionality for it (Stop - Start - Reload)

Answer (score 2):

if you are install Apache 2.4 version in your system, to start restart or stop your Apache server on your local system,then you should run following command

```
./apachectl start
```

or you can use **restart**, **stop** also as per your requirement.
this is tested code

Answer (score 2):

The best way to restart your Apache server is by using the following command:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Alter You can use the below command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Command Source: [Restart Apache Ubuntu](https://www.tecrobust.com/restart-your-apache-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

> systemctl - Control the systemd system and service manager.
>
> systemctl may be used to introspect and control the state of the
>   "systemd" system and service manager.

Answer (score -1):

if you are root: (In Ubuntu root is disabled, I think, than use 'sudo' command!)

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache stop
$ /etc/init.d/apache start
$ /etc/init.d/apache restart
$ /etc/init.d/apache reload
```

(If you used a2ensite or a2dissite, you have to reload your apache configuration)

Comment: `root` isn't disabled, it just doesn't have a password if you don't give it one yourself.

Comment: is `//stop apache` supposed to be a comment?  if so, standard shell notation would be `#stop apache`, `//` doesn't work in bash

Comment: @MikaelAuno root account is disabled if it doesn't have a password

Comment: @xav0989 That's quite the matter of definition. Sure you can't directly log in as `root`, or log in as `root` in any way that requires `root`'s password for that matter, but there are other ways to become `root`. Try for example `sudo -i` followed by `whoami` and you'll see that you are indeed logged in as `root`. Also, if you do `ps aux | grep root` you'll see that you already have lots of processes on your system running as `root`. So, arguably, `root` is not disabled.

Comment: @MikaelAuno or `sudo -E -s`. By disabled I'm assuming that what was meant is that you can't directly login as `root`, but you can still run processes as `root`.

Comment: `$` indicates running commands at non-root. Those commands are unlikely to work outside of root. It’d be better to show `#` to indicate a root shell.