# How can I install MySQL along with phpMyAdmin?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I installed php5 from the Software-Center and it came along with Apache2.

How can I install MySQL database along with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install **phpMyAdmin** open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)  and enter this command: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

To run **phpMyAdmin** open your browser and, in the URL bar put this: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Do no forget to [restart Apache](https://askubuntu.com/q/6358/62483).

Comment: where is `/var/www` set? How would I go about changing it?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/372138/62483). Search on the site or ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

phpmyadmin install command :

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

You need to creat a symbolic link into your `/var/www` for starting phpmyadmin when you type : `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

```
ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
```