# Changed apache www folder

Tags: 13.04, permissions, apache2, mysql, php

So I changed it from `/var/www` to `/home/John/Dropbox/www` and I also did `chmod 755 /home/John/Dropbox/www` but it still says `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

I forgot how to do this, I guess I need to add the www-data usergroup to the folder...I don't remeber anymore, can you guys help me out.

Comment: Did you reboot? Or at least run `sudo apache2ctl restart` in order to allow the changes to take effect. Please inform if you succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work like this:

```
chgrp -R www-data /username/
chmod -R 2750 /username/
```

And also add in apache2.conf

```
<Directory /home/JOgn/Dropbox/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```