# Is there step by step documentation for installing apache on ubuntu?

Tags: installation, apache2

I need to install Apache on Ubuntu.  Which is the simplest way to accomplish this task?  Is there a detailed documentation?  Regards.  Sumo

Comment: `sudo apt-get install apache2`. As you can see, it's very simple to install Apache, configuring it is a different story,but you've not asked about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a community guide to install apache. But is very hard to find a *step by step* guide, because you have to enter just one command to install it.

So for users with few or no experience using a terminal I create this *step by step* guide:

1. Turn your computer on and login into your Ubuntu user
2. Open a terminal, search it in the dash or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Now that you have open the terminal enter the next command:

   `sudo apt-get install apache2`
4. If it request you a password, enter this and press enter.

To see how it works enter the next command or restart your computer (very annoying):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It will [restart apache](https://askubuntu.com/q/6358/62483). Open your web browser and enter `http://localhost` in the address bar.

Further information: [HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/httpd.html) & [ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Installing_Apache_2)