# Apache2 restart does not work when I navigate to it's directory

Tags: 12.04, apache2

This works:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It asks for my password, I enter it and apache restarts.

Then I try this:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo apache2 restart
```

Nope, it doesn't work. Apache displays usage info. Why can't I navigate to the directory and do the restart.

As must by now be obvious, I'm absolutely a newbie. For what it's worth I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you restart Apache?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6358/how-do-you-restart-apache)

Comment: @Anders F. U. Kiær: I don't think the question is about how to start Apache but why it doesn't work the seconds way in the question.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Qustion linked was how to restart apache, and the answers there clearly states the different methods and how they distinct.

Answer (score 2):

If you run

```
sudo apache2 restart
```

the program `apache2` is searched in the folders that the environment variable `$PATH` contains, not in your current working folder. So it doesn't run `/etc/init.d/apache2` but
`/usr/sbin/apache2`.

You can use

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo ./apache2 restart
```

Here `./apache2` calls the program `apache2` that is in the current working folder so you actually run `/etc/init.d/apache2`

Comment: +1 for answering what the OP actually asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to  invoke (stop or restart or start) any service, is to give it's full path name as,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

OR

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it simply by typing

`sudo service apache2 restart`

by the way, can you give the output when you run this command?