# Apache2 error.log

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I am unable to read my `/apache2/error.log` file.
I installed apache2 and its giving me a HTTP 500 error.

```
[Sat Feb 13 12:36:39.114253 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9658:tid 140523880556416] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 13 12:36:39.114321 2016] [core:notice] [pid 9658:tid 140523880556416] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 13 12:36:40.395436 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9658:tid 140523880556416] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 13 12:36:41.469836 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9824:tid 140009621485440] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 13 12:36:41.469934 2016] [core:notice] [pid 9824:tid 140009621485440] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 13 13:15:20.620506 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9824:tid 140009621485440] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 13 13:15:21.686234 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10818:tid 139764134266752] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 13 13:15:21.686351 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10818:tid 139764134266752] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 13 13:15:59.282764 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10818:tid 139764134266752] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 13 13:16:00.374979 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10986:tid 140226625349504] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 13 13:16:00.375030 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10986:tid 140226625349504] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: You can try restarting it and see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6358/how-do-you-restart-apache

Comment: I restarted my server but no success.