# Starting apache2 server from terminal

Tags: apache2

I have installed LAMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04. Now I want to start apache2 server from terminal. What are the commands to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try executing following command

```
$sudo service apache2 restart|stop|start
```

open the web browser and go to the URL http://localhost

if you read

> "It works!"

message on browser

which is the content of the file

> /var/www/index.html

this proves that Apache server has started and it is working.
[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).

Comment: I think '$sudo service apache2 restart' will restart the server. What if the server is down and I want to start it again.?

Comment: here is : http://askubuntu.com/questions/6358/how-do-you-restart-apache

Comment: I think it is the way to restart the server, where the server is already running.

Comment: you can use any of the commands $sudo service apache2 start or $sudo service apache2 stop or $sudo service apache2 restart based on your need.

Answer (score 1):

To start the `apache2` server from terminal run the command as follows.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

To make it start automatically at bootup, execute the command as follows.

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 enable
```

Comment: Don't I need to add '$sudo' before the command to start apache2?

Comment: If you are not logged in as `root`, then yes you have to add sudo. Sorry...